# how to group and sort an array of objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I got an array of object

```
const users= [{
Location: {
  label: "aa",
  value: "aa"
},
Name: "test7"
id: "002"
},
Location: {
  label: "aa",
  value: "aa"
},
Name: "test4"
id: "003"
},

{
Location: {
  label: "ss",
  value: "ss"
},
Name: "test4"     
id: "004"
}]
```

I want to sort the array by  first using Location.lable  then using Name (Ascending order)

Here is what I have already done and it  doesn't work

```
const dynamicSort = property => {
var sortOrder = 1;
if (property[0] === "-") {
  sortOrder = -1;
  property = property.substr(1);
}
return function(a, b) {
  var result;
  if (property === "deviceLocation")
    result =
      a[property].label < b[property].label
        ? -1
        : a[property].label > b[property].label
        ? 1
        : 0;
  else
    result =
      a[property] < b[property] ? -1 : a[property] > b[property] ? 1 : 0;
  return result * sortOrder;
};
};
users.sort(dynamicSort("deviceLocation"))
```

the result should be like this :

```
const users= [{
  Location: {
  label: "aa",
  value: "aa"
},
Name: "test4"
id: "003"
},

Location: {
  label: "aa",
  value: "aa"
},
Name: "test7"
id: "002"
},

{
Location: {
  label: "ss",
  value: "ss"
},
Name: "test4"     
id: "004"
}]
```

how to sort the array object first using Location.label and then with Name. i tried lodash  _.groupBy
and after that sort but it didn't work

Comment: Too lazy to write formatted answer:

users.sort((a, b) => a.Location.label === b.Location.label ? a.Name > b.Name ? 1 : -1 : a.Location.label > b.Location.label ? 1 : -1)

Comment: Please don't paste code with syntax errors to stackoverflow, it's kinda disrespect

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should use JSON or the JavaScript object in your question.

Then, you can create a sort function that first sorts the label of the user's location, followed by the name of the user.

```js
console.log(getUsers().sort(userComparator));

function userComparator(userA, userB) {
  let diff = userA.Location.label.localeCompare(userB.Location.label);
  return diff === 0 ? userA.Name.localeCompare(userB.Name) : diff;
}

function getUsers() {
  return [{
    "Location": {
      "label": "colombo",
      "value": "colombo"
    },
    "Name": "test7",
    "id": "002"
  }, {
    "Location": {
      "label": "jaffna",
      "value": "jaffna"
    },
    "Name": "test4",
    "id": "004"
  }, {
    "Location": {
      "label": "colombo",
      "value": "colombo"
    },
    "Name": "test4",
    "id": "003"
  }];
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: I think you can just do `return userA.Location.label.localeCompare(userB.Location.label) || userA.Name.localeCompare(userB.Name)`

Comment: @Prasanna You could, but the short-circuit `||` hides the `x === 0` meaning. I just wanted to be a little more verbose.